# Error in background script - "Error: browser.tabs is undefined"

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm tring to send message from background script to content script after user click on browser action button.
But I get error after that action - Error: browser.tabs is undefined".

manifest:

```
"browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "./icons/browser-a-64.png",
        "default_title": "Znajdź projekty!"
    },
"permissions": ["notifications", "tabs"],
    
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*.mydomain.com/*"],
        "js": ["./scripts/content_script.js"]
    }], 
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["./scripts/background-script.js"]
    }
```

content script:

```
const scanDOM = (msg) => { console.log;}
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(scanDOM);
```

background:

```
const triggerScan = (t) => {
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(t.id,{"scan": "ok"});
}

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(showNoty);

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(triggerScan);
```

Comment: This code is fine. This error is typically caused by a mistake: trying to use browser.tabs in a content script. If your real extension doesn't have this mistake, the only other explanation is a bug in the browser.